# REST Relationships Besides Parent/Child

Tags: web-services, rest, relationships

This would seem to be a pretty basic question, but I can't seem to find appropraite guidelines for it. What is the "restful" way of `POST`ing a relationship between two entities that are not necessarily parent/child. As an example, consider customers and orders.

One could create a customer with a `POST` to `/customer`. However, what is the best way to create the order? One example would be a `POST` to `/customer/123/order`, but what if the order isn't assigned to a customer directly, and could exist on its own (in the case of a web-cart that allows for "anonymous" checkout)? Is the right way, then, to do `POST /order?customerId=123`

Further, consider the case that an order can be submitted separately from payments (let's say we are invoicing a customer). You could create the order (per either of the methods above), but how would we make the payment? `POST /order/123/payment` or `POST /payment?orderId=123` (if we assume that a payment can be made for something other than an order, and one might want to get information about an order/payment without knowing the specific customer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that if an order is a first class object, use `/order`. If it needs to be associated with one or more customers, the customer ids should be an attribute of the order object.

Comment: But fetching the order would return a full representation of both the order and customer (if one is available, where the customer is a property of the order). It would seem weird to `POST` an id, but receive back a full representation for an object corresponding to that id. Is that common practice?

Comment: Why do you think you would get back both the order and customer? You would get back the order, and one attribute of the order is a customer id or a link to a customer object.

Comment: I'm designing my API such that related entities can be retrieved by specifying a querystring parameter. If you get `/order?expand=customer` it would return the order entity with the customer entity fully expanded. This seems to be fairly common, and is immensely useful from a client perspective.

Comment: @ColinMorelli: That's fine, but so what? The very existence of an `expand` parameter should be a strong indicator to clients that the "expanded" resource *isn't* actually *part* of the main resource and is just related in some way.

Comment: @Aaronaught I agree, but it doesn't change the fact that the `customer` property could be either a simple numeric identifier, or a fully-fledged object. That kind of polymorphism seems weird in a REST api

Comment: @ColinMorelli: You don't generally reuse the property for that. Your ID property follows a convention like `customer_id`, and if you expand it *then* you get the full `customer`.

Comment: @Aaronaught alright, it does still feel weird to me. In your opinion is this approach better than specifying the relationships in the query string, since they identify "where" to create the object, to some degree?